# Do I need to do an air pressure test or can I just turn on the water in my new plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am repiping the entire house with PEX-A and expansion fittings (1 bath, kitchen, washer/dryer, fridge) ...

In general, to pass a city inspection: is a water line air pressure test required or is turning on the water and checking for leaks sufficient?

Comment: It all depends on what your permit authority says is a required test.  I doubt there are the same requirements for water leak tests vs gas leak tests (since it's a lot harder to cap off all water lines than gas for a test).  Depending on what you're re-piping with, if it's a flexible tubing (like PEX), I wouldn't be surprised if it normally slightly stretches under pressure, which would lead towards pressure reduction in your measurements.  Personally, I'd want as many checks as possible, as the last thing I'd want is water leaks in an inaccessible place.

Comment: For the IPC, see [IPC 312.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-3-general-regulations#IPC2021P1_Ch03_Sec312.5). You can get "working pressure" by turning the water back on. It gets referenced from the water supply line chapter if you're interested, [IPC 601.4](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-6-water-supply-and-distribution#IPC2021P1_Ch06_Sec601.4). PVC is the plastic supply line type. PEX is not considered plastic.

Comment: Required _where_ and _by whom_? Please revise to be more specific. (I've never seen an air test done on supply lines.)

Comment: That didn't answer my question. The question at hand is about local enforcement, not your anecdotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your local AHJ only requires a water pressure test, it's *far* less expensive to buy the bits for doing an air pressure test than it is to clean up and repair the mess after you discover a leak under water pressure.

I did an air pressure test and couldn't get the system to build beyond 0PSI... Turned out I had pushed a PEX pipe onto a fitting as I was test fitting things, but forgot to crimp it. I hadn't even put the crimp ring on (which made it a bit easier to find).

Had I waited until I had water in the system, I would have had drywall up, tile in, vanities in place and all fixtures in place. I would have probably noticed pretty quickly that I was getting little to no water pressure at the taps. I *might* have *heard* the water gushing out of the unconnected fitting. Or, I might not have realized it until a chunk of drywall fell off the ceiling...

That would have been *significantly* more expensive that the ~$10 in PEX plugs and ~$20 in valve & pressure gauge and ~$20 in push-connect fittings for the valve & pressure gauge (to make it easier to remove & reuse them in the future).

To be fair, I had completely repiped the original plumbing in my basement many years ago and didn't do any pressure testing for that. However, this basement is a rough, unfinished "root cellar" basement and getting some water spraying around did nothing but get me wet and annoy me because I had to either resolder a copper joint or reglue a CPVC joint. For the finished bathrooms we recently added on, the air pressure testing was a significant potential cost savings.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion of the air pressure test. However I was not as lucky as you. In one home I did a water test.  An uncrimp pex line blew off and water sprayed up a wall all the wall to the ceiling.  I guess it depends on the pressure.  Fixed it, dried stuff out...moved on.

Comment: Since they are doing PEX-A, one of the cool things there is that it's really tough for a join to look right and be wrong. If it's got the ring and it goes up to the ridge or ears on the fitting, it's almost certainly good. I'd still follow your advice though and do the air test.

Comment: It's really hard for a PEX-B joint to look wrong, too, @KMJ. I just managed to overlook the one joint in a place where there were several. Still glad I had air leaking, not water! :)

Comment: I assume I can still do an air pressure test, if I have connecting valves already placed at the toilet, vanity and tube? I would use the kitchen sink rough-in to do the pressure test and I would loop the stub-outs for the water heater. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Sounds right. Having all the device valves in place actually allows you to test those, too. I hadn't installed any of those when I did my pressure testing. You can use any location where you've got hot & cold to join them together, and any other location to put in your valve and pressure gauge. You can test hot & cold separately, but it seems fairly common to join them & make one test of the whole system.